# Remove accents from French date strings

Tags: php, date, strftime, setlocale

I want to display a date in french but without any accent (for french months the is only é and û).

I have this code :

```
$date = '1359887884';
$date = strtotime($date);
setlocale(LC_TIME, "fr_FR", "fr_FR@euro", "fr", "FR", "fra_fra", "fra");
$date = strftime("%A %d %B", $date);
print "<p>date: " . $date . "</p>";
```

The output is : **dimanche 03 février**

How can I display it like this : **dimanche 03 fevrier**

Thanks a lot for your help!

Answer (score 2):

This should do the trick:

```
print "<p>date: " . iconv('ISO-8859-1', 'ASCII//TRANSLIT//IGNORE', $date) . "</p>";
```

Comment: Hi thanks for this quick reply. The result is dimanche 03 f?vrier, it seem that the e wasn't display correctly

Comment: This may be due to the encoding used on your page. See that the encoding specified in the method matches that used on your page.

Comment: Note that the first parameter of the iconv method is the encoding... this needs to match your page.

Comment: Here some info about encoding in the page : mb_internal_encoding = ISO-8859-1; mb_detect_encoding($date) before iconv = UTF-8, and after iconv UTF-8... Thanks again

Comment: Try this: `iconv('UTF-8', 'ASCII//TRANSLIT//IGNORE', $date)`

Comment: Damned, the result is cut just before the accent "dimanche 03 f"

Comment: You are going to have to play with this a bit yourself. Not knowing anything about your pages/architecture, I can only guess as to what may be the problem. The problem almost definitely comes from character encoding, because as you can see in your comment, you were using two different types. You can specify the character encoding of an HTML document using the `meta` tag. This method does work, however, and comes from another well-received SO post.